# openssl перестал корректно работать после переустановки ruby с помощью rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

ситуация вот такая:
устанавливал зависимости для pip, там были вот такие операции:

```
pip3 install --user pipenv
echo "PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
whereis pip
```

после этого у меня отвалились GEM_PATH и GEM_HOME, которые я починил переустановкой текущей версии руби с помощью rvm.

переустановка прошла нормально, без ошибок, но теперь проблемы появились у openssl, который не может найти сертификаты, судя по всему. 
при попытке отправить запрос с помощью RestClient - RestClient.get resource, я получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 
state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer 
certificate))
```

На сервере Rails я использую google recaptcha и теперь, при логине, получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed 
(unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

trace выводит вот сюда:

```
def recaptcha
  redirect_to new_user_session_url unless verify_recaptcha(message: 
  'Проверка не пройдена. Попробуйте еще раз.')
end
```

curl и wget при этом работают нормально, даже с https.
я пробовал следующее:
1. 
  export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
  export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
2. Переустанавливал rvm
3. Пробовал снести и переустановить openssl, лег linux, благо удалось откачать...

кто сталкивался с проблемой? буду благодарен за любую помощь...

**UPD**
только что проверил

```
openssl s_client -connect github.com:443
```

работает отлично... выходит, это не проблема openssl, а проблема rvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем, после долгих поисков и попыток, сработало вот это:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall x.x.x -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```